# API for Commodities Stock markets

Tags: programming, market-data, data, bloomberg, data-mining

I would like to have a clear picture about lithium investments all over the World.

I like [this website](https://www.marketindex.com.au/commodities/lithium) where I can see all companies related to lithium on the Australian Market.

The website also proposes other commodities like nickel, copper, etc...:
[image]

Nice.

But is there any website or API that could provide such information at World scale? I would like to cover US, Latin America, Europe, Asia, etc...

The goal is to create my dashboard through Python, SQL Server and Power BI.

Do you think [Bloomberg](https://www.bloomberg.com/professional/support/api-library/) or Yahoo can provide such API service?

Comment: If you have access to Bloomberg, press F1F1 and explain the help desk what you would like to do.

Comment: No, I don't have access to Bloomberg. I'm looking for a public available API

Comment: Does the free plan include the data you need? On https://www.marketindex.com.au/plans certain "CSV Downloads" are mentioned

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are 2 options I know of that have free accounts. They also offer paid plans that may be worth it if you are willing to pay a small amount.

[Commodities-API](https://commodities-api.com/) - Free public API. Create an account to get an API key. Not a huge offering, just the basics.

[Commoprices.com](https://commoprices.com/en) &
[Commoprices API](https://api.commoprices.com/) - Web query and API access to over 10,000 commodities. There is a free account, but it is pretty limited. This site and API has an extensive offering.